# Ninject failing to load assembly

Tags: assemblies, ninject

I have a system which was using Ninject and loading assemblies using the file pattern kernel load method. Things were working fine with this setup.

A new requirement for the application was to bundle everything into a single exe. We used the technique described [here](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application) for that. Thus to register everything with Ninject we needed to load the assemblies and call the kernel load for each assembly. However, this would not work. Ninject would always fail even though the binding was registered. I saw it in the debugger as being registered and it worked in the immediate window, but not in the code.

The only solution we found was to manually register each NinjectModule.

Is it possible to use Ninject when the assembly is bundled inside of another one?

Comment: can you post your error details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to manually pass in references to the NinjectModule.